# USE DATABASE_NAME doesn't change the database when used in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am able to retrieve for a single database using the below query

```
Select Table_catalog[Instance Name],
Table_name[Database Table],
Column_name[Column],
Data_type[Column Type] 
FROM information_schema.columns
where Data_type in ('varchar')
Order by Table_name,Data_type
```

but I wanted to list it for all available databases in the server

```
  Declare @I int =1,@Qry nVarchar(1000),@DatabaseName nvarchar(100)
   Declare @TempTable Table
(
 Sno Int Identity(1,1),
  DatabaseName Varchar(100)
 )
    Insert into @TempTable
    Select name 
    from sys.databases
    where database_id>4
 Select * from @TempTable
    While(@i<=(Select max(sno) from @TempTable))
        Begin

            Select @DatabaseName=DatabaseName from @TempTable where sno=@i

                Select @DatabaseName
             set  @Qry='Use '+ @DatabaseName
             **exec sp_executesql @Qry**
             set  @Qry= '
                        Select  Table_catalog[Instance Name],
                                Table_name[Database Table],
                                Column_name[Column],
                                Data_type[Column Type] 
                                FROM information_schema.columns
                        where Data_type in (''datetime'',''date'',''time'',''smalldatetime'')
                        Order by Table_name,Data_type'
                 exec sp_executesql @Qry


        Set @i=@i+1
        End
```

Its not working since the use databasename is not actually changing the database and repeat the result set of the database currently in use .. any suggestions on this,

Comment: Your two queries will run on different scope (that's something EXCECUTE sp_executesql does) so the "USE" statement has no effect on the second EXCECUTE.

You should just use schema prefix in your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for this task the undocumented procedure `sp_MSforeachdb`. Just tested on my enviroment at it works flawlessly.

**EDIT**

As Pondlife pointed out, the database part was missing on the three part name syntax. Added and now is correctly working. Also added a `WHERE` clause to avoid searching on unnecessary databases as `master`, `msdb`, `tempdb` and `model`.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 
 'SELECT Table_catalog[Instance Name],
         Table_name[Database Table],
         Column_name[Column],
         Data_type[Column Type] 
    FROM ?.information_schema.columns
  WHERE Data_type in (''varchar'')
        AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'')
  ORDER BY Table_name,Data_type'
```

Just in case you want to know more about this undocumented procedure check [here](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2012/10/its-time-to-retire-sp_msforeachdb/) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/01/31/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb). Remember that undocumented means that officially Microsoft does not support this procedure and therefore it could change without notice.

Sample result from AdventureWorks2008R2 database:

```
 Instance Name        Database Table        Column              Column Type
AdventureWorks2008R2    Customer          AccountNumber            varchar
AdventureWorks2008R2    Password          PasswordHash             varchar
AdventureWorks2008R2    Password          PasswordSalt             varchar
AdventureWorks2008R2    SalesOrderHeader  CreditCardApprovalCode   varchar
```

Comment: tanx This one it gets executed the no of times the COUnt of database available i.e I have 5 databases the query gets executed 5 times

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does. And for each database it runs the query you need to execute to return a list of all columns wich have data type `varchar` on all tables on all databases. Upvote or check as correct answer so others know this is the right answer to your question.

Comment: @Yaroslav, I think that Aran is saying that your query returns exactly the same results, once per database. That's because you forgot to put the database name placeholder in the code: `FROM ?.information_schema.columns`.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Pondlife, I'm editing my answer so it returns back the correct values. Just double checked with AdventureWorks and other databases with different data types, is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL always executes in its own scope, so your `USE` statement has no effect on the second dynamic query.

This should work for you (your loop is unnecessary and awkward):

```
declare @Database sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)
declare Databases cursor local fast_forward
for select name from sys.databases where database_id > 4

open Databases
fetch next from Databases into @Database
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql =  'Select  
                    Table_catalog [Instance Name],
                    Table_name [Database Table],
                    Column_name [Column],
                    Data_type [Column Type] 
                FROM 
                    ' + quotename(@Database) + '.information_schema.columns
                where 
                    Data_type in (''datetime'',''date'',''time'',''smalldatetime'')
                Order by 
                    Table_name,
                    Data_type'

    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from Databases into @Database    
end
close Databases
deallocate Databases
```

Comment: Just yesterday I read [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) which you might find interesting. For SQL Server, the `sys.` catalog views are much to be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pondlife as per your suggestion i could make small changes( pass the database name from outside the scope of dynamic query) and the query returns the result instead cursors i have used while loop

```
      Declare @I int =1,@Qry nVarchar(1000),@DatabaseName nvarchar(100)
       Declare @TempTable Table
    (
     Sno Int Identity(1,1),
      DatabaseName Varchar(100)
     )
        Insert into @TempTable
        Select name 
        from sys.databases
        where database_id>4
     Select * from @TempTable
        While(@i<=(Select max(sno) from @TempTable))
            Begin

                Select @DatabaseName=DatabaseName from @TempTable where sno=@i

                     Select @DatabaseName
                 --set  @Qry='Use '+ @DatabaseName
                 -- exec sp_executesql @Qry**
                 set  @Qry= '
                            Select  Table_catalog[Instance Name],
                                    Table_name[Database Table],
                                    Column_name[Column],
                                    Data_type[Column Type] 
                                    FROM'+quotename(@DatabaseName)+ '. information_schema.columns
                            where Data_type in (''datetime'',''date'',''time'',''smalldatetime'')
                            Order by Table_name,Data_type'
                     exec sp_executesql @Qry


            Set @i=@i+1
            End
```